# Prevent an untracked file from being overwritten in Git

Tags: git

Say I have two branches, `master` and `b2`. In the specific directory where the git repository is, there are many files not tracked by git and some that are tracked by git. I did some work in branch `b2`, and now I tried to switch back to `master` using `git checkout master`.

I get an error saying:

> The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: queries.py

I have two questions:

1. I don't get this message for other untracked files, why for this specific file?
2. I want this file to remain the state it currently is across the different branches (that is, I do not want to overwrite or delete it). How can I do that?

I looked at other questions that mentioned this error. The answers suggested using `git clean` saying it would remove the untracked file, but I don't want to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to track the file or not? (Should it be version controlled by Git?)

If NO:

1. Stash the file: `git add queries.py; git stash`
2. Checkout the other branch
3. Delete the file from the branch, add it to `.gitignore` and commmit
4. Restore the file from stash: `git stash pop; git reset`

If YES:

1. Add the file to Git
2. Checkout the other branch
3. At some point you will probably merge the two branches, and then you will have to decide which version of the file to keep when you commit the merge.

You can choose either way, but you have to decide. It's not normal to track a file in some branches and ignore in others. Either track everywhere or ignore everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to track it. Can you please add instruction on how to restore the file from stash. I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, and I added the stash and related commands in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

That file has been added in one of your branches and is not present in others.  So when you are moving from the branch where it is not tracked to the one that has the file being tracked, you get this error.

When you moved from the branch that had this file being tracked, git made the file untracked when it was updating the state of the code.  Files that are not tracked on the new branch are not removed they remain and become "new" un-tracked files.  Then moving back, git thinks that you are trying to overwrite this file as it exists in the file system.

Start tracking the file in that branch and you won't have the problem.

You can also add the file, do `git stash`, change branches and `git stash drop`  This makes the file seem like it is being tracked.  Stashing will prevent any changes from being overridden and keep changes from being tracked.  When you change branches the file will be created in the state it is on that branch.  Dropping the stash is optional if the file is in a state that you want to retain don't do this step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two follow-up questions (1) Is there anyway I can undo the fact that I added it to master branch; (2) the stash method that you have suggested, will that result in file being maintained in its current state, or will it revert to the state it was in master branch (where it was tracked)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: (1) Depending on the amount of commits that occured afterwards, this may not be worth the work. And if you pushed your changes already and you are not the only one working on the code base, DO NOT DO THIS. You would have to rewind the master history to the changeset before the commit in question, and cherry-pick all needed commits afterwards to a branch of this, and merge this tempbranch back into master. THIS CHANGES HISTORY, AND WILL LIKELY CAUSE HAVOC. (2) Stashing will the the file in the state it currently is, depending on your active branch.

Comment: @sjas: Don't assume she wants to do something stupid. She says she wants to revert the commit introducing the file, and assuming adding the file was the only thing done in that commit there is nothing wrong with `git revert COMMIT_FILEADD`. Otherwise just remove the file in a new commit is just as good.

Comment: @sjas: You can `revert` much more than the last commit (constraint by conflicts basically). The security aspect is something different, but that wasn't in the question.

Answer (score 0):

your 2 Q: add your files to .gitignore to ignore them from git things.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the file is kept versioned, but cannot be changed, make it write-protected.

That it is present in all branches, you have to readd it where it is missing.

Adding it to the `.gitignore` makes it invisible to git, it will not be tracked further. But all working data that is needed should be present in the repository. Any other approach is bad style which will get you sooner or later.